# Prove that if $A$ is complete , So is $A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I came across this Eigenvector Bases proof:

> A) Prove that if $A$ is complete , So is $A^2$

Where the proof is as follows:

Every Eigenvector of $A$ is an Eigenvector of $A^2$ with Eigenvalue $\lambda^2,$ and hence if A has a basis of Eigenvectors, So does $A^2$.

Could anyone help me show an alternative proof ?

Where the second part is:

> B) Give an Example of an incomplete matrix A such that $A^2$ is complete.

I am trying to further my understanding and would like some help expanding on this simple proof . and also how to go about answering the second part of this questions. I think: $$ \begin{pmatrix} 0& 1\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix} $$ is a solution with $A^2=0$

Any help explaining and elaborating would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What part of the proof do you want to elaborate?  It seems quite clear to me.

Comment: Part A. It sounds almost intuitive. I figure you can use the def of an Eigenvector and a A matrix to show this holds true for a basis ?  Not sure though

Comment: Well, “intuitive” is not a criticism of a proof.  Let me be more specific: the proof consists of two very small parts.  1) Every eigenvector of $A$ is an eigenvector of $A^2$.  2) If $A$ has a basis of eigenvectors then so does $A^2$.  Where do you get stuck?  It sounds like you cannot follow 2 because you don’t understand the definition of “basis of eigenvectors” (judging by your confused phrasing).

Comment: I should have been more clear. I was looking for an alternative way to show the proof. Without just stating the definition.

Comment: Every proof is about understanding definitions.

Comment: Interesting that nobody asked "what is a **complete** matrix? The term is undefined in google, and just one single reference exists (as far as I could find) there...precisely from this site itself: a matrix in which every eigenspace's dimension is the same as the eigenvalue's multipliclity....which is exactly the same as saying the matrix is diagonalizable, and then again: why the name "complete"? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

For part A, note that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ such that $Av=\lambda v$ than we have:

$$
A(Av)=A (\lambda v) \iff A^2v=\lambda (Av)=\lambda(\lambda v)=\lambda^2 v
$$

so $v$ is also an eigenvector of $A^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\;A\;$ is diagonalizable ( what you, apparently, call "complete") iff there exists a diagonal matrix $\;D\;$ and an invertible matrix $\;P\;$ s.t. $\;A=P^{-1}DP\;$ , and then:

$$A^2=P^{-1}D^2P$$

and since clearly also $\;D^2\;$ is diagonal we're done.

For (b) take

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\\!-1&0\end{pmatrix}\in M_2(\Bbb R)$$

Comment: Interesting enough you raised a valid question about the definition of a complete matrix. 

The text I am using defined a complete matrix as
> An eigenvalue $\lambda$ of a matrix is called $complete$ if the corresponding eigenspace $\lambda_k=ker(A-\lambda I)$ has the same dimension of its multiplicity . The matrix A is $complete$ if all its eigenvalues are.

Comment: @User2648648 Thanks. May I ask what text book is that?

Comment: Applied Linear Algebra by Peter Olver and  Chehrzad Shakiban.